# I append to new list if they contain a substring, and another if not. The 2nd list is getting the conditions of the first, why?

Tags: python

```
 for i in range(1,len(monitornamelist2)):
        elif monitornamelist2[i].count('') == 1:
            IRoutagelist.append(monitornamelist2[i])
            IRoutagetimelist.append(startindexlist[i])
        elif monitornamelist2[i].count(' ') == 1:
            IRoutagelist.append(monitornamelist2[i])
            IRoutagetimelist.append(startindexlist[i])
        elif monitornamelist2[i].count('Hallway') == 1:
            hallwaylist.append(monitornamelist2[i])
            hallwaytimelist.append(startindexlist[i])
        else:
            roomlist.append(monitornamelist[i])
            roomtimelist.append(startindexlist[i])
```

The list monitornamelist2 contains many strings, between 100-1000, with most of the strings containing these substrings(' ', '', 'Hallway'). I want to make 3 new lists, one is hallway list and one is room list and one is IRoutage list. For some reason, the room list is acting up and has string list entries that contain those 3 strings instead of excluding them. The hallway and IRoutage ones work fine though. How can I fix this?

my desired output is for the room list to exclude those 3 strings.